# Android: add gridview as header of listview

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am trying to add gridview of calendar as header view of my listview. It is working all fine, and gridview is shown perfectly. But now the problem is that I am not able to get the date clicked! I don't know what I am doing wrong..
rLayout is my listview.
Here's my code:

```
gridview= new GridView(getActivity());
    AbsListView.LayoutParams gridParams= new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(height/2.5));
    gridview.setLayoutParams(gridParams);
    gridview.setNumColumns(7);
    gridview.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);

  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id1) {
            if(rLayout.getAdapter() == null){

            }else{
                rLayout.invalidate();

            }
       //some code

    });
    rLayout.addHeaderView(gridview);
```

Here's my xml file:

```
 <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:id="@+id/top_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_image"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout 
         android:id="@+id/calender_cal_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left">
         <ImageView 
              android:id="@+id/calender_cal_img"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/list"
              />

    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
         <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/calender_head_text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Yadda"/>
     </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/calender_new_lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right">

            <ImageView 
              android:id="@+id/calender_new_img"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/new_yadda"
              />
      </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View 
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_header"
    android:id="@+id/head_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"/>

<RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_below="@+id/head_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_image">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#dddddd" >

      <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
            android:visibility="invisible">
        </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#7b898e"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Search" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#0D70B3" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/calender_lay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_view"
    >

<LinearLayout 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cla_topie">
<include 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    layout="@layout/calender_top"/>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/line"
     android:layout_below="@+id/cla_topie"
    android:background="#cccccc"/>
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listie"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
   >

</ListView>
 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: With "i'm not able to get the date clicked" do you mean that it doesn't even enter in onItemClick method?
P.s. Can you post here your xml file?

Comment: i have used simple listview...

Comment: I think that the problem here is that the header is like the first item in the listview, so if you click on it, you will not trigger the event in the gridview but the event in position 0 of the listview, i hope you have understood!

Comment: yes, i got it. Do u have any solutions for the same?

Comment: it is same like adding a fragment with 4 buttons as headerview of listview, and trying to click those buttons....